# Palm tree fruit: green, <yellow>, hazelnut-like dates

Tags: word-request

Generally, a palm tree fruit goes through three phases: green and inedible; yellow and absolutely edible; hazelnut-like and very sweet.

When you hear the word dates, you right away think of the the sweet, third phase date, soft and tasty. However, the hard and yellow fruit is just as good fruit as the soft, sweet one. So what do you call the fruit when it is yellow?

Comment: I don't think such a word exists, we usually refer to fruit as *ripe* if it is ready to eat, *unripe* if it has been picked before it is ripe, and *unripened* if it is not yet ripe but will be in the future. However when there are 3 stages I am not sure we have a word.

Comment: "Semi-ripe dates" could work.

Comment: You could use [green](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/green) or "not fully ripened" (not to be confused with the green color that is inedible). Green bananas are edible even though some prefer them to be riper. This article talks about the different ripeness stages of plantains, and might be helpful: http://www.ehow.com/how_2104862_cook-plantains.html "green", "ripe", "well-ripened", "super-ripe" are some of the descriptions used.

Answer (score 2):

The term for these would likely be "fresh dates". Generally, the brown dates are called "dried dates" or simply "dates" but if you search Google for "fresh dates" instead, you get a plethora of images much as you describe, of bright yellow fruits.

Here's an image of "fresh dates":

[image: Fresh dates]

And one of "dried dates":

[image: Dried Dates]

It is worth noting that, in the US at least, "dried dates" are the normal method of consumption, which is likely why they're generally simply called "dates". It's generally pretty rare to see fresh dates, though there may be some regions where it's more common.

Answer (score 0):

> rutab

is the word you are looking for.

Dates go through three stages or maturity [here](http://homeguides.sfgate.com/ripen-dates-77491.html):

> khalal - hard and bitter
>   rutab - softer and sweeter
>   tamar - fully ripened and sweet

**Tamar** is what most people in the States are used to seeing and experiencing.

**Rutab** is well liked in areas where date consumption is higher and more normal [here](http://saudigazette.com.sa/saudi-arabia/farmers-flood-markets-rutab/).
They are still yellow and on the branch.

Comment: While technically correct, these aren't widely accepted English terms. Or at least I wouldn't expect the typical AmE speaker to understand them without explanation.